# Does anyone have the floorplan for Lord Vauxhall’s summer cottage?

Tags: randall-garrett, lord-darcy

Does anyone have the floor plan for Lord Vauxhall’s summer cottage from Randall Garrett's story "The Sixteen Keys", in *Lord Darcy Investigates*?

As the story is basically Euler's Seven Bridges of Königsberg problem, it's hard to follow the descriptions without the floor plan, and most reprints of the book don't include it.

I swear I found it online, once, years ago, but I'm unable to find it now.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The floor plan is in the original publication in Fantastic, May 1976. [You can read it courtesy of archive.org here](https://archive.org/details/Fantastic_v25n03_1976-05/page/n15/mode/2up).

[image: Floor plan]

Comment: Archive.org: the City Hall of the internet!

Comment: I remember seeing the plan in the first paperback I bought, but it wasn't in the 1983 Lord Darcy omnibus I bought , or in the ebook I bought when I decided to reread it.

Comment: Awesome, will print out and stick in book.